# All razor views adding reference to 'WebApplication1' which doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create some views for my ASP.NET .NET Framework project and for some reason, the Razor page keeps adding a reference to 'WebApplication1' which doesn't exist. This is causing the view to not render.

Here's the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Fhi.jpg

I've already tried to remove the line 'using WebApplicaction1' but it seems it's auto generated when ran.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Change Password";
}

<h2>Change Password</h2>
```

Comment: It looks like issue with your project. Can you create new project and see if it still exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you forgot to remove the `WebApplication1` reference on the web.config on **Views** folder(not the one in the solution folder).

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="WebApplication1" />    <-- Remove this entry
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

All namespace in this `<namespaces/>` section are automatically prepend to the razor view prior to compiling.